# I want to download a npm package using a python script

Tags: python, cmd, npm, subprocess

I have a script in python with a list of the package names and I need to download each package as a zip. I could not find any help so as to download the package within python itself apart from this :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["node","npm" "install", "open"], shell=True)
```

So I assumed i can use subprocess to run cmd commands and tried

```
subprocess.Popen(["npm", "pack", "lodash"], shell=True)
```

where lodash is the package name.
I am not getting any error but it does nothing.I ran

```
npm pack lodash
```

in the cmd in the same directory and it worked. Is there something I am missing?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments
I tried but could not understand much from here...

Comment: are you able to download/install packages without sudo?

Comment: I am on windows!! My organization is forcing me to use it *sigh...In cmd i tried the exact command above and it worked....

Comment: `npm` is a batch file, right? ever tried with `cmd /C npm`?

Comment: How will that help? I need a solution to execute the command in python as that is where I am getting the list of packages...